# Access excel formulas programatically

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have an excel sheet with formulas and I want to write a script to use these formulas in my project.
I tried using openpyxl library but it only reads the formula (e.g. `=SUM(C11:C17)`) or if I use `load_workbook(file, data_only=True)` , it does not update calculations.

Is there a way to use the formulas outside the excel sheet?

Edit:
The table values
| C            |
| ------------ |
| 5            |
| 2            |
| 3            |
| 4            |
| 5            |
| 2            |
| 1            |
| =SUM(C11:C17)|

```
wb = load_workbook(file, keep_vba=True, data_only=True)

ws = wb["Sheet1"]
c = ws['C11']
print(c.value)

c2 = ws2['C18']
print(c2.value)

ws['C11'] = 0

print(c2.value)
```

Result:

```
5
22
22 (expected 17)
```

Comment: `data_only=True` should work fine.Post some of your code

Comment: you need to use `.value` over the cell to get the value

Answer (score 0):

If you need to interact with excel openpyxl is not enough, [xlwings](https://www.xlwings.org/) from Felix Zumstein can do it using com objects.

Other "out of the box" solutions are [pycel](https://pypi.org/project/pycel/) from Dirk Gorissen that can run formulas in a python environment or [XLtoy](https://github.com/glaucouri/XLtoy)[*] that can extract formulas in a convenient way.
[*] I'm the main developer.